# how to fetch only image in php while loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

i am trying to fetch only image from database. In database the table (post_content) have image along with description i only want image. Is it possible? Keep in mind that `$row['post_content']` has image and decription.

```
<?php
    $sql = "select * from wp_tableposts;";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    { 
        echo'Post Contant:'. $row['post_content']. '';
    }
?>
```

Comment: If there's no special field for image in your table, then you have to parse `post_content`

Comment: please tell in detail i didnot understand parse `post_content`

Comment: He was probably thinking about using/breaking `$row['post_content']` with `pathinfo($row['post_content'])` or similar function. Take a look at `pathinfo()` function on php.net manual pages.

Comment: Please provide an example of the data in *post_content*, and the result you want for that example.

Comment: This data is from database `<img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-8" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/1977417_1380086445598132_747645780_n-225x300.jpg" alt="1977417_1380086445598132_747645780_n" width="225" height="300" />this is description`

Comment: i only want image, not description Example:`<img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-8" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/1977417_1380086445598‌​132_747645780_n-225x300.jpg" alt="1977417_1380086445598132_747645780_n" width="225" height="300" />`

Comment: use `substr($row['post_content'],0,strpos($row['post_content'],'/>'))`

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1(Recommended):
Seperate the description and image into 2 columns in the database

Solution 2: 
Differentiate between image and description in the same column using a delimeter (#, or /\ or seperator)